# Broadcom USB Wireless Driver Installation

Tags: wifi, usb, yocto, broadcom, modprobe

I try to use a USB Wireless Stick. The hardware is well recognized with lsusb :

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:bd1e Broadcom Corp. BCM43143 802.11bgn (1x1) Wireless Adapter
```

I tried to install the correct driver with :

```
apt install firmware-brcm80211
```

(https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211)

It installed binaries in /lib/firmware/brcm :

[image]

But i don't understand that i can't load the corresponding module with :

```
modprobe brcmfmac
```

It returns me :

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module brcmfmac not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.70-2.3.2+g8c73bc625c4d
```

Comment: a firmware image and a kernel module are not the same thing.

Comment: Why do you try to manually load the kernel module? That should automatically happen when you plug in the device. If it doesn't, there's probably something wrong.

Comment: I try to manually load the module because it doesn’t automatically. There is no logs into dmesg or systemctl concerning broadcom modules.